# Exact Online reconcile an invoice during pyament provider push with REST API and PHP

Tags: php, payment-gateway, payment, exact-online

I want to reconcile an invoice through the API from Exact Online.
Preferably through REST API, but if only XML is available thats fine aswell (I would need a bit more example code then).

I can't really find a solution on the Exact Online KnowledgeBase for this.

Because we are using a payment provider I get a push signal when someone pays, I want to hook into that and push a reconciliation aswell.
In Exact there wont be a transaction yet because the payment provider pays you out only weekly in one batch with all transactions (so its hard to manualy reconcile all invoices with that one batch payment).

So basicly my question is can I push to reconcile an invoice?
The things I would have is the amount, invoice id and a different GL account which we want to use for it.